# Node.js стрим аудио потока

Tags: javascript, node.js, потоки-данных, streaming

```
  @Get("stream/:id/:name/:server")
  async bookStream(
    @ResponseDecorator() response: ServerResponse,
    @Request() request: ServerRequest,
    @Param("id", ParseStreamInfoPipe) info: CompleteStreamFileInfo, 
    @Param("name") name: string, 
    @Param("server") server: string) {

    
      const url = encodeURI('https//server/audio.mp3');

      const total = info.totalBytes;
      if (request.headers.range) {
        var range = request.headers.range;
        var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
        var partialstart = parts[0];
        var partialend = parts[1];

        var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
        var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : total-1;
        var chunksize = (end-start)+1;

        get(url).pipe(
          response.writeHead(206, {
            'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total,
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 
            'Content-Length': chunksize,
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'
          }));
      } else {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': total, 'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg' });
        get(url).pipe(response);
      }

  }
```

По сути нормально работает.
Проблема в том что когда вставляешь эту ссылку в плеер и при перемотке песни все равно начинается с нуля.
Без разницы куда перетаскивать ползунок плеера.
Проверка на заголовок rаnge есть и при запросе он корректно отправляется.
Как правильно реализовать

Comment: по сути, у вас отдачей потока занимаетесь не вы, а внешний `/server/`, которому вы не сообщили про Range

Comment: да спасибо
сделал так и помогло
get(url, {
          headers: {
            range: `bytes=${start}-`
          }
        }).pipe(
          response.writeHead(206, {
            'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total,
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 
            'Content-Length': chunksize,
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'
          }));
 можешь подсказать а если я например хочу с 1000 по 20000 байты получить как это правильно сделать
@nörbörnën

Comment: или я не пони ваш вопрос или вы не пони заголовок range. пока я думаю, что ответ: передать `/server` заголовок `Range: bytes=1000-20000` и надеятся, что он поддерживает обработку этого заголовка. если не поддерживает тогда вам нужно обращаться с `get(url)` как со stream, прочитать первые 999 байт, выбросить их, читать/отдавать чанками оставшиеся байты пока не прочтёте до 20000, закрыть стрим и отпустить ответ клиента

Comment: @nörbörnën понял попробую